# How to check which specific value occurs in a like statement in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-like

I have a question about like statements and BigQuery. I think maybe what I have in mind is not achievable, but I'm not 100% sure.

I have a query that checks different jobs I have in my working environment regarding several tables and columns that must be updated since they will be deprecated in the following weeks. The query is supposed to give me back the list of jobs that need to be updated.

For this I have a query that gives me the Job_id and then I have two conditional statements. The first one is for checking if one of the update-able tables is on the job_info (a big plain text file that contains data about tables, fields and other things that affect each job in my working environment):

```
AND (job_info LIKE '%table_1%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%table_2%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%table_3%'
```

And the second one for the update-able fields on those tables:

```
AND (job_info LIKE '%field_1%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%field_2%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%field_3%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%field_4%'
   OR job_info LIKE '%field_5%'
```

My objective is to add a 2nd and 3rd column to my query where I can see specifically which tables and columns are the ones in that job.

For example, if Job *123456* has the table 2 and the fields 3 and 4, I would like to see as a final output:

| Job_ID | Tables | Fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | table_2 | field_3, field_4 |

Is something like this achievable in BigQuery? :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select *, 
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(job_info, r'table_1|table_2'), ',') tables, 
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(job_info, r'field_1|field_2|field_3|field_4|field_5'), ',') fields 
from your_table
```

with output like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can query your Tables and Fields columns like this (concatenate case statements and trim last comma):

```
select 
    trim(
case when job_info LIKE '%table_1%' then 'table_1,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%table_2%' then 'table_2,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%table_3%' then 'table_3,' else '' end,
',') as Tables,

trim(
case when job_info LIKE '%field_1%' then 'field_1,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%field_1%' then 'field_2,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%field_1%' then 'field_3,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%field_1%' then 'field_4,' else '' end ||
case when job_info LIKE '%field_1%' then 'field_5,' else '' end,
',') as Fields
```